# IIS Rewrite rule that recognizes Internet Explorer gets confused by Chrome sometimes

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Our website does not support Internet Explorer and therefore we redirect all such users to a page with an appropriate message. This is done in web.config using this Rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="BlockIE" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(Trident|MSIE)" />
          <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="^/no-ie-support.html" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/no-ie-support.html" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Unfortunately, some Chrome users are also redirected to this page and thus cannot use the website.
We are unable to reproduce the problem. I asked one of these users to type "my useragent" into his browser (Chrome), and he got this:

[image]

It looks to me like a perfectly ordinary Chrome useragent, and it does not contain the "(Trident|MSIE)" pattern.

Any ideas what could be wrong with our Rewrite rule (or these users) and how to solve it?

Comment: Try to use this `<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^(?=.*?MSIE)(?=.*?Windows NT 5\.).*$" negate="true" />`.

Comment: Bruce Zhang - I guess you mean to add this as another Input (total 3 Inputs).
Could you please explain why this should help?

Comment: No, use this to place the initial input. This works well in my test.

Comment: Browser side troubleshooting is less effective here (the screenshot does not guarantee showing the user agent your server received but what Google received). Enable FRT and you can then see what the IIS server sees, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: BTW, you should ask your web site developers to implement browser detection, as that's much easier to detect IE using IE specific HTML tags for example. User agent based filtering can give you more false positives.

Comment: Lex Li - that's indeed what I have done - I removed the IIS-side detection and replaced it with Javascript instead. The IIS issue seemed too mysterious as I was not able to reproduce it myself, so I just decided to get rid of this approach. It still remains to be seen whether the problem does not reappear, but I'm optimistic.